# How do you read this form of set builder notation?

Tags: notation, random-variables

I came across this notation while going through a book on statistics. Can someone please help me how to read this?

$
X: \Omega \rightarrow D
$

Here, $\Omega$ represents the sample space, $X$ represents a random variable, and $D$ represents a set of real numbers.

Comment: This is a common way to define a *function*. In this case the function is $X$, the domain of the function is $\Omega$ and the codomain is $D$. This is to say that random variables are functions.

Comment: Thanks, @WaveX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that notation means is that you are mapping the random variables $X$ from your sample space $\Omega$ to some set of real numbers $D$.

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar interpretation in my mind but just wanted to confirm.